# Integrating existing HTML/CSS/JS with Django project

Tags: javascript, html, django, angular, gulp

I'm working on a personal project that involves full-stack development of a Social Networking website. I've build a back-end in Django2.0.5 which supports operations like creating a user, posting content, following other users, etc. While developing this, I tested it by printing information in very minimal HTML pages with no CSS or anything, just data that I can read.

Now I'm at a point where I want to start building the front-end. I bought an HTML project from ThemeForest to get started, but now I am completely lost on how to actually integrate the two. The theme is in a GULP project configured to watch for changes, sync with the browser, and recompile the Handlebars templates.

So far I've looked into:

1. Converting the Handlebars templates into Django templates, and building the front end in Django.

It seems like this method would work, and this is how I started out initially. But, it would take about 10 minutes to convert each of the 100+ pages to a usable Django format before even removing the Lorem Ipsum content

2. Create a new Angular project, add the GULP project into it, and have it communicate with the back-end via REST api

This seems like the most appealing option to me, but GULP and Angular both have an expected filestructure and I can't figure out how to integrate the two. I also can't find any information on how JS frameworks play with Handlebars templates.

3. Work purely with the existing GULP project, and add my own vanilla JS to make AJAX calls to my backend and display the data

This seems like the **simplest** option, but I'm not sure if it would work or if the actions I want to perform are even possible with Vanilla JS. All I want to be able to do is pull objects (title, image, description) from the server and display them in a newsfeed format.

**To summarize, my questions are**:
What is the best way to integrate an existing self-contained HTML/CSS/JS GULP project into Django? What are the advantages of separating the front and back end as opposed to developing it all in Django? And, do I need a JS framework to be able to accomplish the tasks I'm looking for?

I've been stuck at this point for a few days. Please let me know if I can give more info, and thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this will help, but there is a book "Django JavaScript Integration: AJAX and jQuery" by J. Hayward. Maybe it will give the idea how to do that with your framework. Basically, Django's frontend is just templates and static files, so the choice is simple.